# Python Convert Column to Row Issue

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

[Shape1 && Shape2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7gi9.png)

Hi, I'm Trying to processing my dataframe but I have some issues to solve. I have a dataframe like shape 1 and I want to turn it as shape 2. Basicly, I want to change tweets column as row and if there were two or more tweets which are in same days, insert them as a one row next to time section with seperated columns also I want to calculate tweet's polarity and subjectivity which are tweeted in same days.
I'm a beginner of python and I couldn't find solution about it I would be preciated if you guys help me about it.
If there were any mistakes of english sorry for it basicly I want to change My dataframe (shape1) to shape2

Comment: And if there are 100 tweets in the same day?  Or 1000? I don't think that is a sustainable approach

Comment: In my mind there were between 50-100 tweets

Comment: You might be better off with a multi-index for the rows, where level 0 is the date, and level 1 is just an increasing number for the tweets in that day

Comment: It would be a bit easier if you included a sample data set and the code.

Comment: There is a lot of extra math that is occurring in the `subjectivity` and `polarity` columns that you'll have to account for with some math possibly. The short way is to use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with a properly indexed dataframe.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the [ML](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) tag and the [Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag.